# Is a Brad Pitt dummy identifiable as a zombie in the Walking Dead?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, the-walking-dead

In the final episode of the [Battlestar Gallacticast](https://www.syfy.com/syfy-wire/battlestar-galacticast-bonus-the-plan-with-writer-jane-espenson) podcast, *The Plan, with writer Jane Espensen*, at around the 47 minute mark, Tricia Helfer ([Number 6](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_Six_(Battlestar_Galactica))) discusses working on *Creep Show*.

Tricia specifically stared in Episode 1.04b [Lydia Layne's Better Half](https://villainous-beauties.fandom.com/wiki/Lydia_Layne_(Creepshow)).

During the podcast Tricia mentions a discussion with [Greg Nicotero](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greg_Nicotero) who was an executive producer on *Creepshow* and the executive producer, special make-up effects supervisor, and primary director on *The Walking Dead*.

Tricia says that Greg mentioned to her that a Brad Pitt dummy was used as a zombie in the Walking dead. This is due to the effects houses having copies of dummies used in films and TV.

**Has there been any other indication that a Brad Pitt dummy has been used as a zombie in The Walking Dead and if so, do we know where it appears?**